# Third Party DLL events not raised Windows Service - C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-services

I am working on Windows Service Application having third party DLL included as reference.
I am binding one event of third party DLL with event handler like below:

It is supposed to invoke handler when I start exporting video from third party system to show progress count.

```
IExportItem.ProgressChanged += ExportChange_;
IExportItem.Start();

void ExportChange_(ExportState state,ExportProgress progress)
{
}
```

Above event handler does not invoke in case of Windows Service but always gets invoked when I work with this DLL in my desktop application to export video.

I have also tried to change Service Credentials to Administrator but it also did not help. I could not find any helpful material on internet so far.

I am new to Windows Service Development, Can any one please help me?

Comment: Hard to tell, but I bet they send progress via messages, which would require that the application have an message loop. A service often does not, but you can start one.

Comment: How can I start it?

Comment: Create a STA thread which calls `Application.Run`

Comment: I tried below at OnStart function of windows service. 
 var thread = new Thread(InitializeComponents);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start(); 

.It did not help.

Comment: InitializeComponents() is custom function doing windows service start up tasks.

Comment: Usually you have to do ALL your work on the thread which calls Application.Run. Message loops are per-thread. If you create an object that expects to send a message, the thread which creates it better be the one which runs the message loop.

Comment: i have put this code in my service constructor but ddid not help. please let me know if I am doing something wrong. var thread = new Thread(StartService);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start(); ... StartService() method is  : public static void StartService()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MainService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }

Comment: I have also tried putting  [STAThread] at top of Main() method but did not work.